# How to select only a "sin" in string by regular expression?

Tags: javascript

I have a string `sin(asin(sin()))`.

How can I select only `sin` except `asin`
to replace it to 'Math.sin' for example? I need a string like this
`Math.sin(asin(Math.sin()));`

Only js regular please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at word boundaries in Regex:

```
var str = "sin(asin(sin)))";

str = str.replace(/\bsin\b/g, "Math.sin");

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Finally a good answer :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to deal with the 'sin' being at the beginning of the line, then

```
[^a]sin
```

will do it

Answer (score 0):

(Your answer below)
In js regular expressions, there are such things as 'word boundary qualifiers - \b' which help you target a group of characters only if they are not mixed up with others on either side. so, this below should solve your problem:

```
var newStr = 'sin(asin(sin()))'.replace(/\bsin/g,'Math.sin'); 
console.log(newStr); // output - Math.sin(asin(Math.sin()));
```